# Can't figure out how to perform this query

Tags: ms-access

> Physician Table

```
[Phys_ID]
[Title]
[FName]
[LName]
[Address]
[City_ID]
[Prov_ID]
[PostalCode]
[TelNum]
```

> Treatment Table

```
[Patient_ID]
[Phys_ID]
[Treatment]
[Diagnosis]
[Charge]
```

> Patient Table

```
[Patient_ID]
[FName]
[LName]
[Address]
[City_ID]
[Prov_ID]
[PostalCode]
[TelNum]
[Phys_ID]
[Charge]
```

Above you can see the tables I'm working with. I need to create a query that outputs a table with Phys_ID, Physician FName and LName and the total Charge corresponding to each physician. Patients can have visit charges from 1 doctor and treatment charges from another and can have multiple visits and treatments. Can't wrap my head around this. Sum always comes out wrong because of the patients visiting different physicians.

Comment: From your narrative I am left wondering why the Patient table is necessary at all. If you just want the Physician's identification and total charges then you only need the Physician and Treatment tables joined and grouped on the common [Phys_ID] field. The Patient table is only necessary if you wanted the charges further broken down by patient and physician.

Comment: Charge under Patient is a visit charge while treatment charge is a seprate charge. Sometimes a patient visits one physician but gets treatment from another. I need the total charges for all physicians.

Comment: It sounds doable with a Union or Outer Join but I am not currently prepared to set up three tables of sample data to proof a solution.

Comment: I have the data you need, I can email it